# Select All Check Boxes in JSP

Tags: html, forms, jsp, if-statement, checkbox

I want to be able to have a select all check box or button either is fine which will then set the value of all other checkboxes to be checked. Is there anyway of achieving this in jsp? I was thinking of something like this:

```
<c:if test="${!empty param.selectall}">
    //set all others to checked
</c:if>
```

I know the condition works because I've already used it but how do i go about setting a checkboxes to checked inside an if statement.

Comment: will jQuery solution helpful? because I have jQuery solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond @Aniket I have found a solution using javascript. I wanted to use jsp cos thats what I know best.



http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzOJbrrZaiI

Comment: Try this also http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pzCcE/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle link didnt work @Aniket

Comment: The link has worked now @Aniket very useful, if I hadn't already completed it I would have used your solution thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you somehow missed the fact that JSP is merely a HTML code generator.

In HTML, a checked checkbox is represented by the presence of the `checked` attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" ... checked="checked" />
```

All you need to do in JSP is that it generates exactly the desired HTML output.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.selectall}">
    <input type="checkbox" ... checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" ... checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" ... checked="checked" />
    ...
</c:if>
```

Or, if you'd rather not want to duplicate the whole HTML for checked and non-checked states, but just want to generate the desired attribute only:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... ${not empty param.selectall ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
<input type="checkbox" ... ${not empty param.selectall ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
<input type="checkbox" ... ${not empty param.selectall ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
...
```

Or, if you actually have the values in some collection which you could iterate over using `<c:forEach>` and you'd rather not want to duplicate all HTML input elements for every single value, then do:

```
<c:forEach items="${bean.availableItems}" var="availableItem">
    <input type="checkbox" ... value="${availableItem}" ${not empty param.selectall ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
</c:forEach>
```

No need for clumsy JS hacks/workarounds which would fail anyway when the enduser has JS disabled.

Comment: The solution in javascript is simple and works well but like you say @BalusC js can be disabled hence why I wanted to do it in jsp, I didnt forget that I could do it that way I was just over thinking the problem because I'd never done it before. 

Most of my code is like yours but its more about creating tables when if statements conditions are reached or inside of a for:Each.